# Returning the nested object in the cache in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot, spring-cache

I am following the Spring guide to caching here - https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/, but mine is a bit complex object.

For my use case, I have an `Author` field as well. Here is my entire `Book` class.

```
public class Book {

    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private Author author;

    public Book(String isbn, String title, Author author) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Book{isbn='%s',title='%s',author=%s}", isbn, title, author);
    }
}
```

Now, I added another method to fetch book by author id(Assuming only one book is returned). Here is my `SimpleBookRepository`.

```
@Component
public class SimpleBookRepository implements BookRepository {

    private List<Book> books;

    public SimpleBookRepository() {
        books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(new Book("1234", "Some book", new Author(1, "Author1")));
        books.add(new Book("4567", "Some another book", new Author(2, "Author2")));
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable("books")
    public Book getByIsbn(String isbn) {
        simulateSlowService();
        return books.stream().filter(o -> o.getIsbn().equals(isbn)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Book getByAuthorId(int id) {
        simulateSlowService();
        return books.stream().filter(o -> o.getAuthor().getId() == id).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    // Don't do this at home
    private void simulateSlowService() {
        try {
            long time = 1000L;
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I was wondering if I could fetch the `Book` instances from the cache by looking up the `Author.id` in the cache.

Here is my execution and expected behaviour.

```
logger.info(".... Fetching books");
logger.info("isbn-1234 -->" + bookRepository.getByIsbn("1234"));   // Gets the original object
logger.info("isbn-4567 -->" + bookRepository.getByIsbn("4567"));   // Gets the original object
logger.info("isbn-1234 -->" + bookRepository.getByIsbn("1234"));   // Should fetch from cache - WORKS FINE
logger.info("isbn-4567 -->" + bookRepository.getByIsbn("4567"));   // Should fetch from cache - WORKS FINE
logger.info("isbn-1234 -->" + bookRepository.getByIsbn("1234"));   // Should fetch from cache - WORKS FINE
logger.info("isbn-1234 -->" + bookRepository.getByIsbn("1234"));   // Should fetch from cache - WORKS FINE

logger.info(".... Fetching books by author");
logger.info("author-1 -->" + bookRepository.getByAuthorId(1));   // Should fetch from cache - NOT WORKING
logger.info("author-2 -->" + bookRepository.getByAuthorId(2));   // Should fetch from cache - NOT WORKING
logger.info("author-1 -->" + bookRepository.getByAuthorId(1));   // Should fetch from cache - NOT WORKING
logger.info("author-2 -->" + bookRepository.getByAuthorId(2));   // Should fetch from cache - NOT WORKING
logger.info("author-1 -->" + bookRepository.getByAuthorId(1));   // Should fetch from cache - NOT WORKING
logger.info("author-1 -->" + bookRepository.getByAuthorId(1));   // Should fetch from cache - NOT WORKING
```

Is there a way to do that or I would need another cache for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another cache. Just specify in your getByAuthorId method that you want to cache that method as well. Spring will create an entry in cache with key author id and value Book everytime you call that method if it doesn't exist already. Just add the `@Cacheable("books")` to your getByAuthorId method.

So now in your `books` cache you'll have entries with isbn keys and author.id keys that map to Books.

In response to **What I am looking is if the instance was added to cache when getByIsbn() was called, I want to be able to use the same instance when I call getBookByAuthorId()** the only solution I can think of is if you manually add the entry to your cache like:

```
@Component
public class SimpleBookRepository implements BookRepository {

    // inject this bean
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Override
    @Cacheable("books")
    public Book getByIsbn(String isbn) {
        simulateSlowService();
        Book b = books.stream().filter(o -> o.getIsbn().equals(isbn)).findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (b != null && b.getAuthor() != null && b.getAuthor().getId() != null) {
            Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("books");
            cache.put(b.getAuthor().getId(), b);
        }

        return b;
    }

    // ......
}
```

Comment: I did that. However, it doesn't work like I expect. What I am looking is if the instance was added to cache when `getByIsbn()` was called, I want to be able to use the same instance when I call `getBookByAuthorId()`.

Comment: OK, got it now. I don't think that's possible, since Spring relies on the method input args to generate a cache key, and there is no way to correlated the isbn with author.id

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. Anyways, I think there is no straight forward way to do this.